# How to style notifications in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, notifications, growl, css

Growl notifications can be styled using css.

Has anyone made any inroads on styling the notifications in Notification Center in Mountain Lion?

Comment: I don't think you can. Apple OS usually doesn't allow changes like Growl does.

Answer (score 1):

Notification center, like most Apple standard features doesn't provide much in the way of customizable appearance. Even app developers don't have any control over the appearance of the notifications. The most you can do is choose between the *Banner* and *Alert* styles in Notificantion preferences:

[image: notifican preferences]

If you need more styling options, you'll have to keep using Growl where you can.

Comment: Hi, Maybe I should have been clearer. I was not looking for advice on how to use System Preferences. I was thinking about various system hacks such as plist modifications or swapping out particular system resources.There are numerous examples of this being possible, an example might be restoring the interface of AddressBook (now "Contacts") to brushed metal from the new leather-look.

Answer (score 0):

I found this little app called NCbackgrounder here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ncbackgrounder/

or

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/44252/ncbackgrounder/

I think this is what you were looking for. It works pretty well for me so far.

Comment: I took a look at NCBackgrounder, didn't work for me, the developer acknowledges that some bugs need to be worked out... one method that I know actually works is (work only on a copy please!) editing the tiff resources within the application package itself which is in System/Library/CoreServices. The relevant files are in Contents/Resources and are called "banner1line.tiff, banner2line.tiff, banner3line.tiff" ...

Comment: what is not so obvious (maybe not possible) is changing the color of the type used in each banner, and since it's black, it would not work well with dark colored banners... anyway the adventure continues. NB The size of each of the tiffs in question must remain exactly the same, Also, mucking around with your system carries risk! Don't even consider doing stuff like this if you are not comfortable rescuing yourself from whatever weirdness you might cause!